# regular expression to match multiline text including delimiters

Tags: regex, perl

I want to get data between delimiters and include the delimiters in the match.

Example text:

```
>>> Possible error is caused by the segmentation fault

provided detection report:

<detection-report>
This is somthing that already in the report.
just an example report.
</detection-report>

---------------------------------------------
have a nice day
```

My current code is:

```
 if($oopsmessage =~/(?<=<detection-report>)((.|\n|\r|\s)+)(?=<\/detection-report>)/) {
     $this->{'detection_report'} = $1;
 }
```

It retrieves the following:

> `This is something that already in the report.
>   just an example report.`

How can i include both the detection-report delimiters?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the regex to the following:

```
my ($report) = $oopsmessage =~ m{(<detection-report>.*?</detection-report>)}s;
```

Notice I used a different delimiters to avoid the "leaning toothpick syndrome".

The `s` modifier makes `.` match newlines.

The parentheses in `($report)` force list context, so the match returns all the matching groups. `$1` is therefore assigned to `$report`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
if ($oopsmessage =~ #(<detection-report>[\s\S]+?</detection-report>#) {
    $this->{'detection_report'} = $1;
}
```

or, if you're dreading a file line by line:

```
while(<$fh>) {
    if (/<detection-report>/ .. /<\/detection-report>/) {
        $this->{'detection_report'} .= $_;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(<detection-report>(?:(?!<\/detection-report>).)*<\/detection-report>)
```

Try this.Put flags `g` and `s`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xT7yD8/18

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex to get the data with delimiters.

```
(<detection-report>[\S\s]+?<\/detection-report>)
```

Group index 1 contains the string you want.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xE6aD0/6)

`[\S\s]` would match one or more space or non-space characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your regex to the following:

```
if($oopsmessage =~ m#(<detection-report>.+</detection-report>)#s) {
    $this->{'detection_report'} = $1;
}

say $this->{'detection_report'};
```

Using the modifiers `s` allows a multiline match where `.` can be a new line. Using `#` instead of `/` means no faffing around with escaping slashes.

Output:

```
<detection-report>
This is somthing that already in the report.
just an example report.
</detection-report>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/(<detection-report>.*?<\/detection-report>)/gs
```